# Highlight Current page number PHP Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm having problems resolving this so I'm asking for more professional solutions. I have pagination setup for my list of products. Problem is when I switch pages, the active class on the number is not showing or showing wrongly. For example, when users click on 2 (Page 2), it displays the 2nd page of items, but 5 is the one highlighted. Need help fixing this up to highlight the currently being viewed page.

This code is for setting the offset.

```
$totalrows = db_getvalue("select count(buyinfo_id) from buyinfo,user $addtable where buyinfo.user_id=user.user_id $clause $orderbyclause", $global_connection);
        if ($totalrows == "")
            $totalrows = 0;
        $totalpages = ceil($totalrows/$listcount);
        if ($totalpages > 1) {
            $curpageoffset = 0;
            if (isset($_REQUEST['offset'])) {
                if ($_REQUEST['offset'] >= $totalpages)
                    $curpageoffset = $totalpages - 1;
                else if ($_REQUEST['offset']>0)
                    $curpageoffset = $_REQUEST['offset']*$listcount-1;
            }
            $limitstr = " limit $curpageoffset,$listcount";
        }
```

When I go to Page 3 for example, it displays www.site.com/?offset=2

I guess its because of the -1 in $curpageoffset = $_REQUEST['offset']*$listcount-1;

This is the code responsible for the page numbers:

```
<?php
    if ($totalpages>1) {
            echo "<tr><td><ul class='pagination'>";
            echo "<li><a href='' aria-label='Previous' ";
            if ($curpageoffset == 0) {
                echo "onclick='return false;'";
            } else {
                echo "onclick='util_reload(\"posts/?offset=".($curpageoffset-1)."$pageparam\"); return false;'";
            }
            echo " ><span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span></a></li>";

            $tmpctr = 0;
            while ($tmpctr < $totalpages) {
                $curstyle = "";
                if ($tmpctr == $curpageoffset)
                    $curstyle = "class='active'";

                echo "<li $curstyle><a href='' onclick='util_reload(\"posts/?offset=$tmpctr$pageparam\"); return false;'>";
                $tmpctr++;
                echo "$tmpctr</a></li>";
            }

            echo "<li><a href='' aria-label='Next' ";
            if ($curpageoffset >= $totalpages-1) {
                echo "onclick='return false;'";
            } else {
                echo "onclick='util_reload(\"posts/?offset=".($curpageoffset+1)."$pageparam\"); return false;'";
            }
            echo " ><span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span></a></li>";

            echo "</ul></td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've set the value of curpageoffset for use in your query, you can't use it in your pagination code to highlight the page you're on ... I would change  your code this way .. using the original $_REQUEST['offset'] since that's essentially the page number.

```
while ($tmpctr < $totalpages) {
                $curstyle = "";
                if ($tmpctr == $_REQUEST['offset'])
                    $curstyle = "class='active'";

                echo "<li $curstyle><a href='' onclick='util_reload(\"posts/?offset=$tmpctr$pageparam\"); return false;'>";
                $tmpctr++;
                echo "$tmpctr</a></li>";
            }
```

Comment: It worked. Never thought of that! ha! Just additional question if it's okay. Is there any workaround to set the offset to the same page number or that's how it really should work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Could you restate?

Comment: sorry. haven't been clear. for example, if I clicked on 2 (Page 2), the url states www.site.com/offset?=1  i think its because of $curpageoffset = $_REQUEST['offset']*$listcount-1; Is there anyway I can set the offset to be same as the current page?

Comment: I would change your links so they point to the page number (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.) and near the start of your script, set a variable $currentpage = $_REQUEST['offset']-1;  You can then calculate your $curpageoffset using $currentpage instead of $_REQUEST['offset'].  Not sure if that made sense.

Comment: I actually didn't understand what you mean. Sorry for that. Is it possible to have a chat instead? @LuvnJesus

Comment: I had to get to bed so I didn't see your message.  We can do a chat this evening if you still have questions.

Comment: Yes please? If you're free. I'm also going to bed now but will be online again in 9hrs. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101957/discussion-between-cisco1991-and-luvnjesus).