# Pagination change class to "active" with jquery

Tags: php, html

I have following to create  for pagination:

```html
<?php  
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){ ?>
     <a class="pagenumber" href="?p=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Now I want change the class `pagenumber` to "pagenumberselected" if the href from `pagenumber` includes `?p=5` from the current page (`localhost/myproject/downsite?p=5`)

Comment: You don't have to do this with jquery, you can do it with PHP just check if the `$_GET` (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) value for `p` equals `$i`

Comment: But how can I change the class "pagenumber" to "pagenumberselected" with php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight Current page number PHP Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053347/highlight-current-page-number-php-pagination)

Comment: If you want to use jQuery, show us what you've tried. Your question only includes a php function. You can set the class in php as Dan points out, what reasoning do you have for wanting to use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Since the class and link, are set on page load (via php), the class is defined at page load. Clicking the link is going to reload (or change) the page, if you want the class to change when the p = 5, you merely need a php conditional to target that page number and change the class (when the page loads).

```
<?php  
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){ 
   if (i == 5 ) {
?>
     <a class="pagenumber selected" href="?p=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>

<?php  } else {  ?>
     <a class="pagenumber" href="?p=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>

<php  } } ?>
```

I would actually prefer the code below, but essentially they are both the same thing, it just depends on how you feel about echoing HTML as opposed to splitting it from PHP scripting.

```
<?php  
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){
   if ($i == 5 ) {
    //change link where p=5
     echo '<a class="pagenumber selected" href="?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
   } else {
    //all links where p!=5
     echo '<a class="pagenumber" href="?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
   }
 } ?>
```

You *could* do this with jQuery *after* the page loads, by checking the href of the link, then adding/removing classes. But then you're *waiting* for the page to load before implementing the change. By doing it in the php, the page loads as desired without waiting for javascript to load and function.

You could also just use the `$_GET[]` variable to change the page link *whenever* the current page is equal to the link..

```
<?php  
if (isset($_GET['p'])) { 
   $thispage = $_GET['p']; 
} else {
    $thispage = ''; 
}

for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){
   if ($i == $thispage) {
    //change link when link = current page
     echo '<a class="pagenumber selected" href="?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
   } else {
    //all links when link != current page
     echo '<a class="pagenumber" href="?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
   }
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_GET` global array which handles parameters from your url. You can access to it, by parameter name like that: `$_GET['p']`. It's also important to check if the parameter exists. You can achieve this by using `isset` method. Solution:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++): ?>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == $i): ?>
        <a class="pagenumberselected" href="?p=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a class="pagenumber" href="?p=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: you dont need to open and close php tags for each new line, also this question already has answers out there like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053347/highlight-current-page-number-php-pagination  You should also try to include more information in your answer, dont just write a bunch of code with no explanation

Comment: @Dan, you are right. I try to explain it with more details. But not to mixing php and html with closing tags it's more cleaner for me.

Comment: I must check $_GET['p']==$i

Comment: @SebastianHannes I misunderstood the question. Already corrected, thanks.